# Basemap cannot locate .shp file

Tags: python, shapefile, matplotlib-basemap

I am trying to load a shapefile and plot it using basemap, but everytime I try to load the shapefile basemap throws the error that it cannot loacte the .shp file even though the .shp file is in the folder that I am giving it the path to.  Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here?

My code:

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

map = Basemap(llcrnrlon=-86.637575,llcrnrlat=41.855400,urcrnrlon=-82.946169,urcrnrlat=45.116972,
             resolution='l', projection='tmerc', lat_0 = 43.513523, lon_0 = -84.660036)

map.drawmapboundary(fill_color='aqua')
map.fillcontinents(color='#ddaa66',lake_color='aqua')
map.drawcoastlines()

# Shape file location
map.readshapefile('../Desktop/Neighborhoods-MI', 'Neighborhoods')
```

The Neighborhoods-MI folder has Neighborhoods-MI.shp, Neighborhoods-MI.shx, Neighborhoods-MI.prj, and Neighborhoods-MI.dbf files in it. I've also tried just using 'Neighborhoods-MI' instead of the entire path to the file, but nothing works.

Note: I get a deprecated warning as well, but I don't think this is the issue

```
/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mpl_toolkits/basemap/__init__.py:1708: MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: The axesPatch function was deprecated in version 2.1. Use Axes.patch instead.
  limb = ax.axesPatch
/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mpl_toolkits/basemap/__init__.py:1711: MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: The axesPatch function was deprecated in version 2.1. Use Axes.patch instead.
  if limb is not ax.axesPatch:
```

Comment: Try `map.readshapefile(r'..\Desktop\Neighborhoods-MI', 'Neighborhoods')`.

Comment: You have to point to the name of the actual shapefile, not the folder that contains it, so in your case it would be `'../Desktop/Neighborhoods-MI/Neighborhoods-MI'` (assuming your on a Unix-based system, on Windows, you still have to replace the `/` by `\`).

Comment: Oh, I just realised that the `\ ` was escaped, so here again: on Windows you have to replace the `/` with `\ `.

Comment: I am programming on a Mac so I believe the / are correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to point to the name of the actual shapefile, not the folder that contains it, so in your case it would be '../Desktop/Neighborhoods-MI/Neighborhoods-MI'

What you are currently pointing to is just the folder that contains the fil.